# php force download extension

Tags: php

I'm trying to force a download so this is my code:

```
$file = 'test.m4r';
$mime = 'audio/aac';
header("Pragma: public"); // required
header("Expires: 0"); 
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-Type: $mime");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));          
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
readfile($file);
```

The file extension should be .m4r, even though the mime is aac. On some computers it's downloaded as test.m4r, while on other computers, the file has extension of **test.m4r.acc**. How do I fix this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can lie about the mimetype, but besides that there isn't anything you can do. 
Try:

`"application/octet-stream"`

This might work, and is the default for unknown filetypes etc.

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
<?php header("Content-Type: application/force-download"); ?>
```