# How to download a file through my server to the client? PHP

Tags: php, file, download

There's a file on a server. The file is a ZIP file.

The file has to be downloaded through my server to the client.

I tried using the readfile function but instead of downloading a file it just displays wierd symbols...

I uploaded it here: http://b-games.co.il/test/download/

This is the code:

```
    $file = "2title3.gif";
if(file_exists($file))
{
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
}
```

I also tried using this:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/some.url';
$src = fopen($url, 'r');
$dest = fopen('php://output', 'w');
$bytesCopied = stream_copy_to_stream($src, $dest);
```

But it did the same thing... Just displayd wierd symbols.

What am I doing wrong?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php
Here it says it should work...

An important update:

On my localhost the same code works!

Anyone knows why?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have *any* kind of error description? "It doesn't work" is ambigious

Comment: You said the file is a zip file, but your script points to a gif file - just pointing that out

Comment: Sorry, I was triyng the ZIP file at the beggening but then switch to the gif.

Comment: I said it just dispays wierd charecters and I gave a link... http://b-games.co.il/test/download/

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php 
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=file.gif');
header('Content-type: image/gif');
readfile('file.gif');
```

You can try something like this, beware about settings the right content-type.

Comment: You can use finfo_file to get the mime-type on the fly. http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php

Comment: Don't output anything apart for the readfile! Try it here: http://ebenum.es/downloadfile.php, it will ask you to download a file named php.png with a PHP logo.

Answer (score 0):

Already this **worked** ..

```
<?php
session_start();
$a=$_GET['a'];
$parts=explode("-",$a);
$tres=$parts[0];
$nombre=$partes[1];
$dbcodletra=substr($tres,2);
if($dbcod!=$_SESSION["username"])$boolt=0;
if($ext==1) $extl=".jpg";
if($ext==2) $extl=".jpeg";
if($ext==3) $extl=".tif";
if($ext==4) $extl=".tiff";
if($ext==5) $extl=".pdf";
if($ext==6) $extl=".doc";
if($ext==7) $extl=".docx";
if($tipoproy==1) $dir="rute/".$dbcodletra."/".$nombre.$extl;
if($tipoproy==2) $dir="rute/".$dbcodletra."/".$nombre.$extl;
if($tipoproy==3) $dir="rute/".$dbcodletra."/".$nombre.$extl;
if($tipoproy==4) $dir="rute/".$dbcodletra."/".$nombre.$extl;
if (file_exists($dir) && $boolt) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($dir));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($dir));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($dir);
    exit;
}else echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Refresh\" content=\"0;url=misdocumentos.php\">";
?>
```

from 
[php-image-file-download-by-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773812/php-image-file-download-by-code)

Answer (score 0):

It's seem a duplication of [php-force-download-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359226/php-force-download-extension).

The "real" problem (IMHO) is that you've already generate an output, and you have not ob_start() at the beginning of the code, so ob_clean() do nothing.

EDIT

this your PHP modify to **download** only the GIF

```
<?php
ob_start();
// put some business here 
$file = "2title3.gif";
if(file_exists($file))
{
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();

readfile($file);
exit;
}
```

EDIT 2

I look at your example code, may be I found what you really want to do.
Try a look to this [example](http://codepad.org/5eVeZGk0).

Using HTTP you can send **only one** mime type per request, so you need 2 requests: one for for the HTML (showing the example) and one for the download (pressing submit button).

Comment: I see a lot of HTML and PHP **before** your GIF

Comment: Have you tried my example? If yes, **why** it don't perform well?

Comment: Yes. On my local server everything works. But on my actual server, it doesn't

Comment: this is an unusefull answer, because you don't say what you expected from the code, you show only a snippet of code and finally say "on my PC works".

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a problem on your server. Switch on your PHP error reporting on your Virtual server and tell us what it say. At the moment everything that should be working inst working. If all else fails maybe try JavaScript.

Comment: It works on my local host... How do I switch to error reporting?

Comment: What virtual server are you using? WAMP or XAMP you can just click on your tray icon, go to PHP > PHP settings > display errors. It might show us something you arent seeing, on a virtual/localhost you can set the ideal system and online servers dont always support all of the functions.

Comment: Maybe look into JavaScript... [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery. Are you using cheap shared hosting? Have you checked what PHP version they are running? Make sure your host is capable of supporting what you want, i run all my web apps on Hetzner Hosting and never had problems. I tested Adirael link and it worked fine.